# usage of random numbers in recursive loop

Tags: numerics, random, code-review

I am trying to evalute two functions using iterative process as below

```
S[i+1] = S[i] (1+ r*dt +vol*w *sqrt(dt)) for i= 1 to nts and for j = 1 to path.
Optionprice [j] = Max (S[nts] - strike) for j = 1 to path
```

Output of 1st iterative process (`S[nts]`) is input of 2nd (to compute Parameter `Optionprice`) as in below code. Both iterative process involves usage of random no generated using parameter `w`. However `Nest` function is not generating new values of `w` (or new random no.). `w` is updated only for `For` loop. Can anybody help in modifying or simplifying the code so that I can generate random no for two Paths and use the output of 1st path (`S`) to compute parameter in 2nd path please. I am expecting a value close to $10$ when I run below function as

```
mcOptionPrice[10000,10,1,100,0.05,0.2,100]
```

I only get that for `nts =1` when I increase it more than $1$ (say $10$) `FVMC` diverges away.

```
mcOptionPrice[paths_,nts_,T_,strike_, r_,vol_, S0_] := Module[{dt,stock,optionprice,df,w,S,FVMC},
dt = T/nts;
stock=optionprice = Table[1,{paths}];
df= Exp[-r*T];
For [ i=1, i <paths+1, i++, 
w=RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0,1]];
S=Nest[# *(1+r*dt+vol*w*sqrt(dt))&,S0,nts];
stock[[i]]=S;
optionprice[[i]]=Max[S- strike,0]];
FVMC = df*Mean[optionprice];
FVMC
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two small issues in your code.

1. You have incorrect syntax in your `Nest` statement that assigns a value to `S`. `sqrt` is not defined. I think you want `Sqrt` and will have to change your brackets as well.
2. Use `SetDelayed` (`:=`) for assignment of `w` to have it re-evaluated each time in the `Nest` statement.

Hope this helps.